# Do close/reopen/delete votes disqualify one for the Frosty the Snowman hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

The description for "Frosty the Snowman" is "all cast votes on a day are upvotes." Obviously, this means that down-voting a question in a day disqualifies you for the hat that day -- but are votes to close, reopen or delete also included in the computation for whether or not one is awarded the hat?

Comment: A way to know is to test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the usage of close, reopen and delete votes does not disqualify you.

I earned the hat and did all three actions that same day. You simply can't downvote - that is all.

Comment: What about spam flags (which carry an implicit downvote)